# How to use Timer in Smartface App Studio

Tags: smartface.io

I want to use Timer in my app with interval of 3secs. How to use this component. I gone through [SmartfaceTimerDoc](http://docs.smartface.io/html/AllMembers_T_SMF_UI_Timer.htm) But, didn't get complete info. 
Can any one help on this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example which initiate the function after 3 sec

```
var timeoutID;

function setHello() {
    timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
            alert("Hello");
        }, 3000);
}

function cancelHello() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. I tried with this which is working fine earlier. But, i want to use Timer control. Where exactly we can use that?

Comment: In Smartface timer object is no more in use as it was defined in release notes. 
(http://www.smartface.io/release-notes/4-4-0/)

You should use it as Alex defined.